# Strange JSON.toString() format PHP to Android

Tags: php, json

I'm just a simple guy working my way through passing JSON from Android, and I've come across a strange problem.

To better understand how JSON works between PHP and Android, I started by created a Json (OK) passing it to PHP and echoing the exact same file back - just to see what happens.

The problem is that the outgoing JSON.toString() is as follows:
{"Age at Death ":32.5,"Enemy":"Darius","Battles":["Issus","Arbela"],"Death":-323}

But the returning JSON.toString() is:
{\"Age at Death \":32.5,\"Enemy\":\"Darius\",\"Battles\":[\"Issus\",\"Arbela\"],\"Death\":-323}

This throws an error when I try to read the Json from PHP. (PS: this is one problem I've identified; maybe the source is elsewhere, so don't let me set you on the wrong track)

Here is my code:

Android:

```
private void connectToURL() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        String url = "http://www.this.url.is.correct.php";

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        String hello = myJson.toString();
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Json", myJson.toString()));

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));

        //ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String myResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            showResponse(myResponse);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void showResponse(String thisResponse) {
        try {
            JSONObject newJson = new JSONObject(thisResponse);

            viewer02.setText(newJson.toString(2));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and here is the PHP (it doesn't get simpler than this):

```
<?php

$obj = $_POST['Json'];
//$json = json_encode($obj);
//$string = $json->{'enemy'};

echo $obj;

?>
```

Comment: Hey zerkms you were right! I learned a lot from your comment. Can't you answer my question so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because of magic quotes options turned on in php.

IIRC it's currently deprecated and actually isn't recommended to use (because of it makes no sense)

Comment: It's actually deprecated in PHP 5.3 and removed in PHP 5.4. Finally.